# same height Bootstrap columns with vertical align

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3, I need to have same height of the columns with vertical align able in the content of the columns

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
     vertical align top
  </div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
     vertical align middle
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
 <img src="http://mspmentor.net/site-files/mspmentor.net/files/archive/mspmentor.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/free_managed_services.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
     vertical align bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check here https://jsfiddle.net/4d2m74nc/4/

Comment: can you create a fiddle of your code.

Comment: I have already updated

Comment: try this. may be help you. https://jsfiddle.net/4d2m74nc/

Comment: you can also try this.http://jsfiddle.net/mnM5j/2/  [copied]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4d2m74nc/1/  @AwaisNawaz

Comment: you can fix the height.

Comment: is there any option to do it height auto? @AwaisNawaz

Comment: If you want to do it with auto height. Then height will automatically changes according to content

Answer (score 10):

This is achievable but will take away from some of bootstrap's built in functionality.  Mainly, the media queries for mobile rendering of the grid system.

The best way to achieve this is probably with the flexbox approach.  [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/tZ6bz71x42).

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
         vertical align top
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 vcenter">
           vertical align middle
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <img src="http://mspmentor.net/site-files/mspmentor.net/files/archive/mspmentor.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/free_managed_services.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 vbottom">
         vertical align bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
.vcenter{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  }
.vbottom{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

Second way is to use absolute positioning for the vertical alignment and flexbox for matching heights.
Check out the [demo](http://www.bootply.com/r8IdtfldDc).

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
         vertical align top
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="vcenter">
           vertical align middle
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <img src="http://mspmentor.net/site-files/mspmentor.net/files/archive/mspmentor.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/free_managed_services.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
         vertical align bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
.vcenter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Another option would be to use JavaScript to fix the heights and vertical align for you.  You could use [matchHeight.js](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height).

It's fairly simple to use.  You just wrap all of your column content that you want to match in height with another `<div>` with the class `.box`

```
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">
            Content 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">
            Content 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box">
            Content
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

and then instantiate it on document load in your JavaScript file or `<script></script>` tags after your JQuery link.

`$('.box').matchHeight();`

Sticking with JavaScript for the vertical align you could add `.vcenter` to the `.box` element you want vertically aligned and do something like:

```
var height = $('.vcenter').height();
$('.vcenter').css('margin-top', (height/2));
$('.vcenter').css('margin-bottom', -(height/2));

var $window = $(window);
var windowsize = $window.width();
function checkWidth(){
  if (windowsize < 440) {
    $('.vcenter').removeAttr("style");
  }
}

 $(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

Which calculates the height of the `.box` and then divides by 2 to determine a top and bottom margin for the content.  We then determine the width of the window and on resize we remove the margins.  This part is **untested** but I believe will work in theory.  Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23042/) of [matchHeight.js](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height).  And [here's](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/different-tricks-on-how-to-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height) a useful blog on column height matching in bootstrap.

The last two approaches to vertical alignment are poor but should work.

Comment: what about vertical-align:bottom?

Comment: @ElvisMilan On the first approach, same principle as `.vcenter`.  Use a class and set the `top` attribute to like 90%.  The second approach, just change your divisor to like 1.5.  So `(height/1.5)`.

Comment: @ElvisMilan I added a better flexbox approach to the top of my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row flex-container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 flex-item col-sm-3">
        vertical align top
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 flex-item col-sm-3">
        vertical align middle
    </div>
    <img class="col-xs-6 flex-item col-sm-3" src="http://mspmentor.net/site-files/mspmentor.net/files/archive/mspmentor.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/free_managed_services.jpg" />
    <div class="col-xs-6 flex-item col-sm-3">
        vertical align bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS that support the boxes the **flex item properties it just give for your understanding**

```
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: what about vertical-align:bottom; @Yaswanth?

Comment: Add "-webkit-flex-direction: column;"  property at  ".flex-container"  Class

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I found an interesting solution, I hope it works for you, greetings.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-stretch bg-primary">
            <div class="align-self-center">
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-stretch bg-primary-subtle">
            <div class="align-self-center">
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-stretch bg-secondary">
            <div class="align-self-center">
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```